# How to send a client SSL certificate to server by using CFStream in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ssl, websocket, certificate

We have a WebSocket security server working on SSL. We hope to put a client SSL certificate in our iOS client, in order to ensure the security when communicating with server.

Because we are using WebSocket, in iOS client, we use [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)(Objective-C WebSocket client library) to implement WebSocket communication.

The problem is I have no idea on how to send my client SSL certificate to server.

I can set the properties of CFStream, like `kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel`. But I don't know how it works. And I can't find any docs about certificate in CFStream.

I know that when we need to connect to a HTTPS server, we can use `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` in NSURLConnection. But And as I know, there wasn't a counterpart in CFStream.

Could someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a lot of study and trying, I can answer myself now. Also hope it'll be useful for you.

Actually, what I need is implementing client SSL authentication by using CFStream. So I need to do these:

1. Put PKCS #12 file in my app bundle
2. Read this file as `NSData` to `pkcsData`
3. Use method `SecPKCS12Import` to import `pkcsData`
4. Get identity and cert from the data you imported above, and generate a certificates array
5. Set the array to key `kCFStreamSSLCertificates` in `kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings` of your `CFWriteStreamRef`

Sample code below:

```
  // Read .p12 file
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"client" ofType:@"p12"];
  NSData *pkcs12data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

  // Import .p12 data
  CFArrayRef keyref = NULL;
  OSStatus sanityChesk = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)pkcs12data,
                                         (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary
                                                                    dictionaryWithObject:@"123456"
                                                                    forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase],
                                         &keyref);
  if (sanityChesk != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Error while importing pkcs12 [%ld]", sanityChesk);
  } else
    NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate.");

  // Identity
  CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(keyref, 0);
  SecIdentityRef identityRef = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                                                    kSecImportItemIdentity);

  // Cert
  SecCertificateRef cert = NULL;
  OSStatus status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef, &cert);
  if (status)
    NSLog(@"SecIdentityCopyCertificate failed.");

  // the certificates array, containing the identity then the root certificate
  NSArray *myCerts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef, (__bridge id)cert, nil];

  //
  [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots];
  [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates];
  [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
  [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];
  [SSLOptions setObject:@"test.domain.com:443" forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
  [SSLOptions setObject:(NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:(NSString*)kCFStreamSSLLevel];
  [SSLOptions setObject:(NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:(NSString*)kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel];
  [SSLOptions setObject:myCerts forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates];
  [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLIsServer];

  [_outputStream setProperty:SSLOptions
                        forKey:(__bridge id)kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];
```

Because I use SocketRocket, I've added these code in my own fork: https://github.com/nickcheng/SocketRocket

Comment: Just what I needed for a quick-turn-around project!  Thanks for posting the code.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! I wasted so much time on this. Well done